# BufferReader not receiving data from socket apparently. Simple chat service

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, bufferedreader, serversocket

Could You kindly take a glance at my code and tell me what could be the problem here?
I am learning java network programming and networking in general for fun and i try to follow this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html but instead of creating protocol i try to just create simple exchange of messages between server and client.

Nothing shows up in standard output and when i am debugging it BufferReader buffer is empty and seems to not receive data. I have yet to check it with Wireshark but i suspect cause is much more trivial and a result of my inexperience.

Here is the **client code** (It messages server first with a simple "Hello There")

```
 try(BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ){

        toServer.println("Hello there!");

        while(!goodbye){
            if(fromServer.ready())                        //if stream is empty this prevents a freeze
                msgFromServer = fromServer.readLine();
            if(msgFromServer != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + msgFromServer);
                if(msgFromServer.equals("Bye"))
                    goodbye = true;
            }

            msgToServer = consoleInput.readLine();
            if(msgToServer != null) {
                toServer.println(msgToServer);
                if(msgToServer.equals("Bye"))
                    goodbye = true;
            }

        }
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And now **server side**:

```
      try(Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
            BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter toClient = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ){

            while(!goodbye){
                if(fromClient.ready())
                    msgFromClient = fromClient.readLine();
                if(msgFromClient != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + msgFromClient);
                    if(msgFromClient.equals("Bye"))
                        goodbye = true;
                }

                msgToClient = consoleInput.readLine();
                if(msgToClient != null) {
                    toClient.println(msgToClient);
                    if(msgToClient.equals("Bye"))
                        goodbye = true;
                }

            }

            socket.close();

        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

I am a bit confused already by all the loops and wonder if it is possible they are out of sync somehow and my strategy is generally wrong ? perhaps should i set some flags as "waiting_for_server_reply" I am really confused

Edit: **After commenting out** `if(BufferedReader.ready())`
**methods in each class it worked**. I am still unsure why though so i won't close it just yet but after i find answer i will explain in separate answer
So far my 'fixed' code looks like:

```
 try(Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
            BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter toClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ){

            while(!goodbye){
                //if(fromClient.ready())
                    msgFromClient = fromClient.readLine();
                if(msgFromClient != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + msgFromClient);
                    if(msgFromClient.equals("Bye"))
                        goodbye = true;
                }

                msgToClient = consoleInput.readLine();
                if(msgToClient != null) {
                   toClient.write(msgToClient);
                   toClient.newLine();
                   toClient.flush();                        
                    if(msgToClient.equals("Bye"))
                        goodbye = true;
                }

            }

            socket.close();

        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

I forgot but i also added `Socket.TcpSetNoDelay(true)` to client Socket

Comment: “After commenting out `if(BufferedReader.ready())` methods in each class it worked. I am still unsure why though…”  [The documentation for ready()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready()) explains it.  All ready() does is tell you if reading will return immediately or will need to wait for input.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be using BufferedReader for this purpose. BufferedReader/Writer are designed for using with large files. They improve throughput by buffering the data. You, on the other hand, want to handle the data more immediately. You may still want to use Reader and Writer, though.

Comment: @VGR ohhh so it didnt answer immediatly because its never immediate to send data basically but on the second message it already had something to read so it was immediate naturally. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use familiar classes for reading and writing. For example if you are using `BufferedReader` for reading then you should use `BufferedWriter` for writing.

Comment: Hey thanks i changed it to BufferedWriter and do these methods BufferedWriter.write(sth), then .newLine() then flush() and its kinda working although with a delay for each message. It doesn't show "Hello there" in server standard output unless i type and send something from server.

Answer (score 0):

After commenting out `if(BufferedReader.ready())` methods in each class it worked.
It looks like i had wrong idea what this method is doing.
I added the .ready() method because server froze on .readLine() because i didn't use flush() method after writing to the stream from the client and during debugging it indicated that there may be a problem here.

As @VGR pointed out
All the `ready()` method does is telling whether there was a delay waiting for stream data to arrive or not. First message had to have a delay so it didn't show until the next buffer read when it was already something in the buffer.

I also added `Socket.TcpSetNoDelay(true)` to client Socket

Code now looks like this
**Server:**

```
try(Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
        BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter toClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ){

        while(!goodbye){
            //if(fromClient.ready())
                msgFromClient = fromClient.readLine();
            if(msgFromClient != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + msgFromClient);
                if(msgFromClient.equals("Bye"))
                    goodbye = true;
            }

            msgToClient = consoleInput.readLine();
            if(msgToClient != null) {
               toClient.write(msgToClient);
               toClient.newLine();
               toClient.flush();                        
                if(msgToClient.equals("Bye"))
                    goodbye = true;
            }

        }

        socket.close();

    } catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

**Client**

```
Clientv2(){
    socket = new Socket();
    try {
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true); //this is new too
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void connect() {
    try {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverHostname, serverPort));
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    try(BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter toServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ){

        toServer.write("Hello there!");
        toServer.newLine();
        toServer.flush();

        while(!goodbye){
            //if(fromServer.ready())                        //culprit
                msgFromServer = fromServer.readLine();
            if(msgFromServer != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + msgFromServer);
                if(msgFromServer.equals("Bye"))
                    goodbye = true;
            }

            msgToServer = consoleInput.readLine();
            if(msgToServer != null) {
                toServer.write(msgToServer);
                toServer.newLine();
                toServer.flush();
                if(msgToServer.equals("Bye"))
                    goodbye = true;
            }

        }
        socket.close();
```

Comment: 'All the `ready()` method does is telling whether there was a delay waiting for stream data to arrive or not': this is not correct, and it is not what @VGR told you. It tells you whether there is data available to be read *now*, without blocking.